# Can't insert anything in MongoHQ database

Tags: mongodb, mongohq

I registered for a free `sandbox` database on [MongoHQ](http://www.mongohq.com/).

As I am starting to use mongoDB I thought it would be a good idea to connect to MongoHQ database from the mongo console and run some commands before using it in any program.

I tried connecting to my database using:

Here `testuser` is my username and `123456` is my password (I know posting user id and passowrd on forums is bad, this user is temporary and will be deleted by me later).

`mongo oceanic.mongohq.com:10076/tnh_data -u testUser -p 123456`

and I got this:

`MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: oceanic.mongohq.com:10076/tnh_data`

Hoping that everything is running fine I tried running a few commands, but I am getting a not authorized error.

```
> show dbs
Sat Apr 19 22:00:18.090 listDatabases failed:{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:46
> use learn
switched to db learn
> db.collection0.insert({name: 'Harry', gender: 'Male'})
not authorized for insert on learn.collection0
```

Please help me what am I doing wrong ?

Just for the information. I created the users using the web interface on mongoHQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using MongoHQ sandbox plans and logging in from the console, there are a couple of things that are at play:

1. When you connected, using the string above, you are already in your database (tnh_data)
2. You do not have admin-level access, so "show dbs" will not work in MongoDB console.

So, in MongoDB console, connect again using the same string you started with and, once connected, run this command: "show collections".

Also, without trying to switch to another database, run your insert again. It should work normally this time.

Hope this information is helpful!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things for me.

Can you please tell me how to get admin-level access.
And thus how to add and remove databases.

Sorry for these newbie questions. I am pretty new to MongoDB.

Comment: You can add additional databases through the MongoHQ web interface. If you want the ability to add multiple databases to a single MongoDB deployment, MongoHQ has Elastic Deployments. These allow you to create multiple databases and have increasing levels of access.

Is there something specific that you need admin-access for? It does not come standard with the free/sandbox plans.

Comment: Thanks Jason . I just wanted to know how to get admin access. I don't have got to do anything with it now. I thought that this information will be handy in future.